# Enumerate through data structure objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have the following data structure. I want to add a new object to a new array that will store my markers.

```
({ title = "1";
   location = "2";
},
{
   title = "3";
   location = "4";
})
```

How do I set each marker so that the first object in the new array has the property marker.title with the value of 1 and marker.location with the value of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class for that, and add objects of that class to the array.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *location;

@end
```

I have set the types to NSString for now, though you can change it to your preference.

You can create and add objects to array as follows:

```
MyClass *newObject = [[MyClass alloc]init];

newObject.title = @"1";
newObject.location = @"2";

//Adding to array
[arr addObject:newObject];
```

For fetching, you can implement:

```
for (MyClass *obj in arr)
{

    NSLog (@"title: %@, location %@", obj.title, obj.location);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to enumerate 'fast enumeration' is much quicker than a for loop:

```
[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    YOUR_OBJECT *current = obj
    ......    

}];
```